# ffmpeg deinterlace yadif=1 with NTSC to PAL converted VOBs

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

[image: From PAL DVD that was probably converted from NTSC]I have some VOBs that were stream copied from PAL DVDs, although the original work was NTSC produced in N. America. Sample image is Full frame image.

When converting the aforementioned I use ffmpeg with yadif=1 the deinterlacing does not work correctly

I have used YADIF=1 with NTSC and PAL sources , some of which had been PAL to NTSC converted it all works fine, but a handfull of these have been converted the other way NTSC to PAL and the YADIF=1 seems to fail on all of them.

ffmpeg -i "in.vob" -vf yadif=1 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 17 -vf yadif=1,scale=960:720 out.mp4 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 256 out.mp4

Is there an alternative that may work aside from 1/2 the resolution which is unacceptable? I get great results with other sources.

Comment: "deinterlacing does not work correctly". What is wrong with the deinterlacing?

Comment: After attempting several PAL DVDs (with American Artists , meaning they were probably already converted NTSC to PAL ) , I get the same result. Iage added to OP

Comment: Lazy test is to switch parity. Try `yadif=1:parity=bff` and `yadif=1:parity=tff`. Also, only use one instance of `-vf`. You have two in your command so one is being ignored.

Comment: BFF and TFF options do not solve the issue.I believe those are for Interlacng order Bottom/Top Field First.

Comment: Yes, it was the simplest thing to try. Without a sample I could only provided guesses.